# HTML/CSS Fluid Grid: How to overlay div to another div

Tags: html, css, web, fluid-layout

I'm really having a hard time researching for an answer. I tried to make my div: absolute but it will ruin the whole fluid grid. All I want is to put the div over the background div. Thanks in advance!


**CSS**

```
#mannequin {
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
width: 60%;
padding: 0 12px;
margin: 0;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

#products {
clear: both;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
z-index: 10;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mannequin"><img src="http://tinypic.com/r/29596hh/9"> 
<div id="products"><img src="http://tinypic.com/r/2qw09lc/9">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do u want..do u want to make a div as a overlay of whole page?

Comment: Nope, just on the #mannequin div like: mannequin div is the base and the #products div is the thing that will be on top or will overlay.

Comment: where is `#mannequin` and `#products` in you html.

Comment: oops sorry, I changed the names. Haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `height:100%` to `#products` and top left to 0.

```
#mannequin {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#products {
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appeared that the image is too huge.

Comment: what do you mean by that??

Comment: Woah, I got it but the product div won't fit exactly on the mannequin div. It has a space. I tried to edit the height, width and top but won't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

please make one Div position: relative; and other div make position: absolute;